# 400 error with nginx subdomains over https

Tags: nginx, https, subdomain, gunicorn

Not sure what I'm doing wrong, but I'm trying to get gunicorn/django through nginx using only https.  Here is my nginx configuration:

```
upstream app_server {
    server unix:/srv/django/app/run/gunicorn.sock fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443;
    server_name app.mydomain.com;

    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.key;

    client_max_body_size 4G;
    access_log /srv/django/app/logs/nginx-access.log;
    error_log /srv/django/app/logs/nginx-error.log;

    location /static/ {
        alias /srv/django/app/data/static/;
    }
    location /media/ {
        alias /wrv/django/app/data/media/;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_pass http://app_server;
    }
}
```

I get a 400 error on `app.mydomain.com`, but the app is published on `mydomain.com`.  Is there an error in my configuration?

Comment: Please post errors from your nginx error log. Do you get error from gunicorn or nginx? 

It would be good to get result of curl -L -v http://app.mydomain.com.

Comment: Hunting down the logs, I discovered that the django backend "ALLOWED_HOSTS" option did not include the subdomain.  Adding that resolved the 400 error, but I can still access the site on the root domain.

Comment: Please provide more info as requested. I don't see actual anything wrong in your nginx configuration. You can add server_name to part with 80 port. 

It's not clear what you are trying to achieve and what's working wrong for you. Errors from log and output of curl will help.